# Dynamically change a css image with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I need too change an image in css that when a button is clicked it matches a slide image.

The slide images are populated using a list, basically you click through the lists and the relevant image come up.

Here's the css for those images

```
.hero li:nth-child(1) span { 
  background-image: url('http://image1.jpg');
}
.hero li:nth-child(2) span { 
  background-image: url('http://image2.jpg');
}
.hero li:nth-child(3) span { 
  background-image: url('http://image3.jpg');
}
```

Here's the jquery i've got so far

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".trigger-wrapper").click(function () {
    $("#menu-wrapper-left").stop().animate({width: 'toggle'});
    $('#hero-container').css('background-image','url(http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg)');
    return false;
  });
});
```

But this is a static image and only selects the 1st image, I need to run along side the slider, any ideas?

Here's a fiddle, the slider doesn't work on the fiddle for the moment but you can see what i'm truing to achieve. http://jsfiddle.net/H863X/4/

If I've forgotten something and you need a little more info, let me know.

Comment: what does width `'toggle'` do? Are you sure that'd work? I've never seen it used before like this.

Comment: there is syntax error! $('#hero-container').css('image1.jpg)'); but in your fiddle that's correct. please check properly.

Comment: Thanks, I edited it to make it more readable, I've now corrected it.

Comment: still wrong in your question code. put exactly as your fiddle.

Comment: I've now changed it to match the fiddle.

Comment: @Joeytje50 The toggle allows it to slide, I will change this slide technique after I sort this issue as it does't seem to flow as nice as a css transition, but one problem at a time.

Comment: U are changing the hero-container bg css but the other image bg are for child elements if its changing also u can't see it, u have to change to particular element. http://jsfiddle.net/H863X/10/

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong - the image is applied to the `span` but your jQuery code is changing the `background-image` of the `#hero-container`.

take the image off of the `span` (last line of your css) and you should see the container is changing beneath it.

Comment: To change the span use `$('.hero span')` instead

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#hero-container').addClass( "yourClass" );
```